# running through tree recursively with global variable

Tags: java, tree

I'm trying to get an array with all the elements of a BST tree in order (min to max). I decided to go for a recursive method. My idea is to call the following helper method to the left of the root element and then to the right of it, all the while adding elements to an arraylist variable (the List you see on the code below). However for this approach to work I would have to define a variable that can be accessed by both calls to SortTree (the left and the right one). I don't know how to do that. Anyway: the code below returns an empty list when called on the bst tree with elements {3, 4, 7, 8, 10, 11, 15}; Can anybody help me understand why? I am also open to improvements in my idea. It's probably best not to use global variables.

```
public List<Integer> SortTree(Node node) {
    List<Integer> candidate = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    if (node.getLeft() != null) {
        SortTree(node.getLeft());
    }
    else
        {
        candidate.add(node.getValue());
        if (node.getRight() != null) {
            SortTree(node.getRight());
        }
        else
            candidate.add(node.getValue());
    }
    return candidate;
}
```

Comment: You want to make the `candidate` variable common to every call to `SortTree` function ? Your function is surely declared in a class, define `candidate` as an attribute of the class

Comment: I would prefer avoiding that at the cost of modifying my approach. Is there a recursive approach that does not require global variables?

Comment: Why not just add the list return by subcall to candidate ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this code works for me with a home-made Node class:

```
  public List<Integer> sortIt(Node node) {
        return SortTree(node, new ArrayList<>());
    }

    private List<Integer> SortTree(Node node, List<Integer> result) {

        if (node.getLeft() != null) {
            SortTree(node.getLeft(), result);
        }

        result.add(node.getValue());

        if (node.getRight() != null) {
            SortTree(node.getRight(), result);
        }

        return result;
    }
```

the sortIt method is the method to call

Comment: for the algorithm, go deeper as you can to the left, get the node value when you have no more left child, and then explore the right part

Comment: also about your question regarding a global variable, the sortIt method API handles the creation of a local variable which will contain the result of the sort

Comment: well if you are inside the Tree class, I guess you should have the root node as an attribute member of the class. pass it to the SortIt method. please post the Tree class code, It may be easier for me to answer accordingly

Comment: Glad to have helped you.

Comment: Also about your original post, it was the else branching which breaks the algorithm rescursivity. You'll get used to it while working with this kind of algorithm.

Comment: How do you think the else branching was breaking it? You mean in general I should try to avoid elses when implementing recursive stuff?

Comment: Not exactly. I wanted to point out that for a given node as you explore the left child branch in the if statement, you’ll never explore the right child branch in the else. The first thing you should do when designing a recursive algorithm is thinking about the stop condition of the recursivity. With tree structure it is usually exploring both left and right subtree of a node

Answer (score 0):

I can't really test this, because I don't have a `Node` class, but you could try the following:

```
public List<Integer> sortTree(Node node) {
    List<Integer> candidate = new ArrayList<>();
    sortTree(candidate, node);
    return candidate;
}

private void sortTree(List<Integer> candidate, Node node) {
    if (node.getLeft() != null) {
        sortTree(node.getLeft());
    } else {
        candidate.add(node.getValue());
        if (node.getRight() != null) {
            sortTree(node.getRight());
        } else {
            candidate.add(node.getValue());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should just add the list return by a sub call to your current list

```
public List<Integer> SortTree(Node node) {
    List<Integer> candidate = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    if (node.getLeft() != null) {
        candidate.addAll(SortTree(node.getLeft()));
    }
    else if (node.getRight() != null) {
        candidate.addAll(SortTree(node.getRight()));
    } 
    candidate.add(node.getValue());
    return candidate;
}
```

Comment: does this preserve order? I need to write the array in order, I'm sorry if this was not clear.

Comment: I'm not sure, try and tell me